# Keep a Zenity dialog box always-on-top in foreground

Tags: zenity

Is there a way to detect that a `Zenity` dialog has lost focus?

I would like to keep the dialog box in the foreground unless the user presses <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

I am attempting to add it to [this script](https://github.com/rubo77/mouse-speed/blob/master/usr/bin/typebreak#L20):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# requires these packages from ubuntu repository:
# wmctrl, zenity, x11-utils 
# and the script mouse-speed

# This procect on git:        https://github.com/rubo77/mouse-speed


######## configuration ##########
# seconds between micro breaks
microbreak_time=$(( 10 * 60 ))
# micro break duration in seconds
microbreak_duration=15
# seconds between long breaks
longbreak_time=$(( 120 * 60 ))

# message to display 
message="Try focussing a far object outside the window with the eye to relax!"
longbreak_message="Change your seating or continue work in a standing/sitting position"
#postpone label
postpone="Postpone"

window_title="typebreak"

# global zoom of your window manager:
ZOOM=2
# height in px of the top system-bar:
TOPMARGIN=57
# sum in px of all horizontal borders:
HORIZONTALMARGIN=40
# get width of screen and height of screen
SCREEN_WIDTH=$(xwininfo -root | awk '$1=="Width:" {print $2}')
SCREEN_HEIGHT=$(xwininfo -root | awk '$1=="Height:" {print $2}')
# width and height
W=$(( $SCREEN_WIDTH / $ZOOM - 2 * $HORIZONTALMARGIN ))
H=$(( $SCREEN_HEIGHT / $ZOOM - 2 * $TOPMARGIN ))

function slow_down(){
    #zenity --warning --text "slow down mouse";
    mouse-speed -d 30
}

while true; do
    # short loop every few minutes to look around
    sleep $microbreak_time
    (
    echo "99"
    sleep $(( $microbreak_duration - 2 ))
    echo "# Mouse speed reset to 100%"
    sleep 2
    echo "100"
    ) | if ( sleep 1 && wmctrl -F -a "$window_title" -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz && sleep 3 &&  wmctrl -F -a "$window_title" -b add,above ) & ( zenity --progress --text "$message" --percentage=0 --auto-close  --height=$H --width=$W --pulsate --title="$window_title" --cancel-label="$postpone" ); then
        #zenity --info --text "Maus normal speed!"
        mouse-speed -r
    else 
        slow_down
    fi
done &
while true; do
    # second long loop to change seat position
    sleep $longbreak_time
    zenity --warning --text "$longbreak_message" --title="$window_title - long break"
done
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/197099/zenity-window-on-top

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# This will wait one second and then steal focus and make the Zenity dialog box always-on-top (aka. 'above').

(sleep 1 && wmctrl -F -a "I am on top" -b add,above) &
(zenity --info --title="I am on top" --text="How to help Zenity to get focus and be always on top")
```

Source:

- http://wp.shaibn.com/how-to-help-zenity-to-get-focus-and-be-always-on-top
- and http://pastebin.com/VUsBevqy

Comment: I wonder if `add,fullscreen` will also work

Comment: I also added ` -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz` in a second wmctrl call. Now I need to [call the script also if the zenity window is minimized, resized or moved](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/154182)

Comment: At startup things may get really slow, so I suggest this: `(while ! wmctrl -F -a "$$ the title" -b add,above;do sleep 1;done) &` and also put the script pid on title to make it more unique.

Answer (score 1):

You may run into problems if you run this as a cron job. Cron's environment is not aware of your X display, dbus or desktop and will not display the zenity box or keep it on top. Adding DISPLAY=:0 prior to **both** wmctrl and zenity resolves the issue:

`(sleep 1 && DISPLAY=:0 wmctrl -F -a "I am on top" -b add,above) &
(DISPLAY=:0 zenity --info --title="I am on top" --text="How to help Zenity to get focus and be always on top")`

Answer (score 0):

This solution is mostly the same as the one by @Jan,
but uses the PID instead of the window title to identify the window,
and additionally is Bourne Shell compatible (-> does not require bash).

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# This will wait 200ms, steal focus and set the Zenity dialog box
# to "always-on-top".

modify_win_by_pid() {
    pid=$1

    sleep 0.2
    win_id=`wmctrl -l -p | grep ${pid} | awk '{print $1}'`
    wmctrl -i - ${win_id} -b add,above
}

zenity --info --title="I am on top" --text="I received focus and will stay on top" &
modify_win_by_pid $!
```