# call a script if a zenity window is minimized, resized or moved

Tags: window-management, zenity, wmctrl

I would like to add an event-catcher, if my the `zenity` window gets minimized, resized or moved.

I already call a script if the window is closed or the button is pressed in my [typebreak script](https://github.com/rubo77/mouse-speed/blob/d80fb6ccf2d2e0f5390e995de015cf7cecd4b69d/usr/bin/typebreak)

But I would also like to catch minimizing, resizing and moving of the zenity window too, so I can then also call the `mouse-speed` script inside my `typebreak` script.

I use Unity on Ubuntu but the script already works on different window-managers too.

Comment: See the related topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718154/how-can-my-shell-script-control-the-placement-of-a-zenity-window for some pointers. Instead of devilspie, you should probably use the successor [devilspie2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/manual.php) Apart from that you forgot an important fact: What window manager do you use?

Comment: I use Unity on Ubuntu but the script already works on different window-managers too.

Answer (score 0):

As my previous answer has been deleted and converted to a comment, which I cannot edit nor add a new one, additional information:

I don't think you can do that with zenity alone. zenity would have to forward the information on such window events, which it doesn't for resize and minimizing/maximizing . You would basically have to implement the event handler in an ugly loop that iterates over the state of your window. If you do that, it would probably be easier to write your own small QT/QML/whatever application for this.

wmctrl can do the resizing and minimize/maximize, but you would have to catch the events to trigger it. devilspie can catch those events, but that altogether would be pretty hackish.

Can you elaborate a bit on the overall use-case? Why not simply pin your window to a fixed position, and add a button to it that minimizes then zenity dialog, which you can then handle within your script via wmctrl and return values of the zenity call?

Comment: The overall use will be a pop-up for my typebreak program that will give a penalty when you do not take your break